# Units of CAtransform3d

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am exploring CAtransform3d with GPUImage.  What are the units used by CAtranform3d? I could not find that in the documentation but I assumed it should be pixels for translation and radians for rotation. But when I use it for translation by just 1 pixel using the GPUImageTransformFilter, the image gets translated across half of the screen of iphone. (I am converting UIImage to GPUImage and back again after processing and setting it to UIImageView). Could somebody please point out what could be the mistake?

```
CATransform3D matrix = CATransform3DIdentity;
matrix.m41 = 1; // since the convention of CAtransform3d is transpose of normal transformation matrix
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:oldUIImage];

        GPUImageTransformFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];

        [stillImageFilter setTransform3D:matrix];

        [stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
        [stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [stillImageSource processImage];

        UIImage *newUIImage = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the normalized OpenGL units which goes from -1 to +1 in both x and y (with bottom-left origin)?

Comment: I am not really aware of opengl concepts. By normalisation do you mean normalisation by image width and image height in case of translation

Comment: Normalized as in 0 to 1, but in this case -1 to +1.